# SQL Server 2008 : replace string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string

I have a table with an erroneous symbol('�') in a number of rows in one column.

The TSQL script below does not work.

```
UPDATE S
SET S.Offering_Details = REPLACE(S.Offering_Details, '�', '...')
FROM tblSacrifices S
```

The column in question has datatype of nvarchar(230) and allows null entries.

The data came from a csv file converted from Excel an d via a Visual studio windows app. The data originally was '...' but I think perhaps word/excel classed this as one character (rather than 3 separate '.'). When my application read the original string from CSV file it (unintentionally) replaced the '...' with '�' before submitting the data into the database.

PLEASE help

Comment: What's the datatype of the affected column?

Comment: Hi Ed it's nvarchar(230). Also the column allows nulls(if that makes a difference).

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the symbol in the data is the black diamond with the question mark and not that it is just being displayed as such because of a charset issue? Or perhaps by being a character not displayable in the font you are viewing it with?

Comment: Martin, you could be onto something there. The data originally was '...' but I think perhaps word/excel classed this as one character(rather than 3 seperate '.'). When my application read the original string from CSV file it replaced the '...' with '�' before submitting the data into the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.
Thanks all for your help.

I had to convert to binary. All unicode characters above 65500 require this as normal REPLACE() doesn't work.

```
UPDATE S
SET S.Offering_Details = REPLACE(S.Offering_Details, nchar(65533) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, '...')
FROM tblSacrifices S
```

Comment: You are replacing one character with three so the result can be longer. Can you not just use the elipsis single character ` N'…'` (Otherwise I think you will need to make the column wider or use `LEFT` to truncate yourself or `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` to ignore the error and allow truncation.

Comment: I see Thanks Martin. I just extended the max allowable characters for the column as I didn't want to lose any of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try being explicit that the character you are searching for is nvarchar by using a leading N:

```
UPDATE S
SET S.Offering_Details = REPLACE(S.Offering_Details, N'�', '...')
FROM tblSacrifices S
```

**UPDATE**
Based on the discussion from Martin's answer:

I've no reason to think that this is functionally any different that what I've posted above, but you could try:

```
UPDATE S
SET S.Offering_Details = REPLACE(S.Offering_Details, NCHAR(65533), '...')
FROM tblSacrifices S
```

**UPDATE 2**

I didn't read Martin's code closely enough before updating my answer. Because it uses the SQL server `UNICODE` function to display results, the actually error character is masked by 65533.

See [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) for details of unicode char 65533 - it's the generic unicode value for bad data.

Comment: Thanks Ed but this doesn't work either. Please see my reply to Martin in my original post. Some extra info may assist in answering the question. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks both of you. As you probably already know that doesn't work either. Is there a way perhaps to remove the 'bad data' and then replace but then we wouldn't knwo where to put it. I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Following update in comments try `REPLACE(S.Offering_Details, nchar(65533), '...')`

**Original Answer:**

This might help you troubleshoot it

```
declare @s nvarchar(230)

SELECT @s= ProblemCol
FROM YourTable
WHERE ProblemRowId = X;


set @s = N'日本国'; /*For testing*/


WITH N AS
     (SELECT 1 idx,
             LEFT(@s,1)ch,
             UNICODE(LEFT(@s,1)) C

     UNION ALL

     SELECT idx+1,
            SUBSTRING(@s,idx+1,1),
            UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@s,idx+1,1)) C
     FROM   N
     WHERE  idx<LEN(@s)
     )


  SELECT idx, ch,C
  FROM     N
```

Result of Test

```
idx         ch   C
----------- ---- -----------
1           日    26085
2           本    26412
3           国    22269
```

Comment: By the way - "Results to text" in management studio seems to handle these chars better than results to grid - at least with my setup.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I've put the results in the my original post. They're the same as yours. I'm unsure what this means though.

Comment: @Chris - Yes sorry I meant for you to delete this line `set @s = N'日本国'; /*For testing*/` it was just to give a demo of what it would return. Once you find out the problem character code(s) you could do Replace with `nchar(26085)` or whatever if you just want to get rid of them.

Comment: I see now, the results returned a value of 65533 for the symbol '�'.

Comment: @Chris - If the decimal value for the mystery character is 65533, I'm pretty confident that the script in my answer should work.

Comment: So far as I can see from the Unicode site character lookup http://www.unicode.org/charts/ there is no such character. Does `REPLACE(S.Offering_Details,  nchar(65533), '...')` work?

Comment: @Ed - Why do you say that? `select unicode('�')` gives 63 for me not 65533

Comment: @Martin Smith - I get 65533 from `select unicode(N'�')` - if you don't include the N, you get `'?'`, which is 63

Comment: @Ed - Doh! Absolutely Correct. I guess I was probably using the unicode lookup charts wrong then.

Comment: @Martin - I've updated my answer with a bit more detail. Still no fix, though

Answer (score 0):

Use the Unicode function like this, it might help you:

```
UPDATE S
SET S.Offering_Details = REPLACE(S.Offering_Details, NCHAR(UNICODE('�')), '...')
FROM tblSacrifices S where S.Offering_Details like '%�%'
```