# SQL Server 2008 R2 : detect encoding in nvarchar field

Tags: unicode, encoding, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a 1,000,000 rows plus string table, that has some garbage inside due to encoding errors.

The garbage is minimal, but needs to be found.

The column in question is a `NVARCHAR` column that normally contains text in one of 11 languages.

All of the text should be unicode (utf-8 when we process it application side).

The corrupt columns contain `?` characters and or a very limited unusual glyph set, by eye they can be very easily seen not to be valid language. It is likely that these columns have been encoded backwards and forwards into total garbage.

So in the name of speed, is there anything I can do on SQL Server to detect bad encoding / string garbage?

Thanks.

EDIT to add garbage example:

This was Russian  Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ð˜Ð¼Ñ Ð£Ñ‡Ð°ÑÑ‚Ð½Ð¸ÐºÐ°

Comment: It has either been imported from php using the sqlsrv driver without the utf-8 flag,  or prior to that using mssql driver.  Some may have been moved in sql 'copy and pasting'!  from table to table varchar to nvarchar and back perhaps.  Some is imported from spreadsheets (through php, perhaps trying / or not, to re-encode).  Some will be bad html form, ajax and php file encoding.  Sorry I cant be more specific.  It has a huge legacy.

Comment: I don't expect to be able to recover any of this data, just hopefully a fairly quick way of flagging it, so that it can be looked at.

Comment: [Does anything here help?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333952/73226)

Comment: Yes quite possibly, digesting now.  Thanks